# Process all file present in subdirectories

Tags: perl

I want to process all the files (starting with `proc` and ending with `log`) present in subdirectories.

I have tried below code:

`$InputDir`: i am taking this from command line:

```
find(
  sub { print $File::Find::name, "\n" if /Proc(.*)log$/ },
  $InputDir
);
```

I want to take all the files along with full path in the array.

Comment: What is wrong with your code as it stands? It looks like it should work, but it finds all files that *contain* `Proc` and end with `log`. You may want to try `/^proc.*log$/i` instead.

Comment: Yes till this part it is fine, but i want to store all filtered file along with full path  in an array , so that i can process all of them in a further loop.

Answer (score 2):

To *store* the file names instead of just printing them, push them into an array:

```
my @files;
find(
  sub {
    push @files, $File::Find::name if -f and /^proc.*log$/i;
  },
  $InputDir
);

print "$_\n" for @files;
```

The `-f and` checks that the item found is a file, and not a directory.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a task for [File::Find::Rule](http://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule)

```
use File::Find::Rule ;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                          ->name( 'Proc.*log' )
                          ->in( $InputDir  );
```